# Logs are not received in Hawkular APM from Zipkin Client

Tags: apache-camel, openshift, zipkin, hawkular, distributed-tracing

I have client application instrumented with Zipkin library with configuration in spring application.properties .

```
camel.zipkin.host-name=hawkular-apm-server.com
camel.zipkin.port=443
camel.zipkin.include-message-body-streams=true
```

Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-zipkin-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The hawkular apm server console is reachable from the local machine.

However, when the rest api exposed in the client application is invoked, the zipkin trace is logged but they are not collected at the hawkular apm server.

```
04:31:55.632 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.s.CamelHttpTransportServlet - Initialized CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet, contextPath=]
04:31:55.668 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.camel.zipkin.ZipkinTracer - clientRequest [service=MyCamelClient, traceId=-5541987202080201726, spanId=-5541987202080201726]
04:31:55.672 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.camel.zipkin.ZipkinTracer - serverRequest [service=MyCamel, traceId=-5541987202080201726, spanId=-5541987202080201726]
04:31:55.676 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.camel.zipkin.ZipkinTracer - serverResponse[service=MyCamel, traceId=-5541987202080201726, spanId=-5541987202080201726]
04:31:55.677 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.camel.zipkin.ZipkinTracer - clientResponse[service=MyCamelClient, traceId=-5541987202080201726, spanId=-5541987202080201726]
04:31:55.758 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  o.a.t.transport.TIOStreamTransport - Error closing output stream.
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.close(TIOStreamTransport.java:110)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.close(TSocket.java:194)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.close(TFramedTransport.java:89)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.ScribeClientProvider.close(ScribeClientProvider.java:96)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.ScribeClientProvider.exception(ScribeClientProvider.java:75)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.log(SpanProcessingThread.java:123)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.log(SpanProcessingThread.java:109)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.call(SpanProcessingThread.java:95)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.call(SpanProcessingThread.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
04:31:55.763 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  c.g.k.b.scribe.SpanProcessingThread - Logging spans failed. 1 spans are lost!
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at com.twitter.zipkin.gen.scribe$Client.recv_Log(scribe.java:74)
    at com.twitter.zipkin.gen.scribe$Client.Log(scribe.java:61)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.log(SpanProcessingThread.java:127)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.log(SpanProcessingThread.java:109)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.call(SpanProcessingThread.java:95)
    at com.github.kristofa.brave.scribe.SpanProcessingThread.call(SpanProcessingThread.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am not sure if its a configuration issue at client application, as the Hawkular APM UI is opening properly.

As per my understanding, Zipkin client can be integrated with Hawkular apm by simple replacing the hawkular url in place of zipkin server, but this does not seem to work.

Any suggestions on this, unfortunately I could not find any examples too.

Comment: Tried setting up zipkin server in local, still same issue. Any help please?

Comment: is your project based on Spring Boot ?